# how to install and use open-tamil package?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to use the open-tamil package for processing tamil text. 
I downloaded it as "open-tamil-master" package which has a setup.py file. but on running the file it says "error no commands supplied". 
also available in https://github.com/arcturusannamalai/open-tamil
can some one say me how to install and use it??

Comment: have you installed `python-dev` in your system?

Comment: I tried the pip install Open-Tamil and its installed now. but i still dint figure out how to install using the setup. Thank u.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To download and install (using setup.py) open-tamil you can do the following

```
git clone https://github.com/arcturusannamalai/open-tamil.git
cd open-tamil
sudo python setup.py install
```

*it says "error no commands supplied"*

That is because you need to tell setup.py what to do by supplying a command. In this case that is `install`.

Now you can import its modules etc:

```
tim@tim-N53SN:~$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Feb 27 2014, 19:58:35) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import transliterate
>>> import tamil
>>>
```

The full list of what commands you can supply to setup.py:

```
Standard commands:
  build            build everything needed to install
  build_py         "build" pure Python modules (copy to build directory)
  build_ext        build C/C++ extensions (compile/link to build directory)
  build_clib       build C/C++ libraries used by Python extensions
  build_scripts    "build" scripts (copy and fixup #! line)
  clean            clean up temporary files from 'build' command
  install          install everything from build directory
  install_lib      install all Python modules (extensions and pure Python)
  install_headers  install C/C++ header files
  install_scripts  install scripts (Python or otherwise)
  install_data     install data files
  sdist            create a source distribution (tarball, zip file, etc.)
  register         register the distribution with the Python package index
  bdist            create a built (binary) distribution
  bdist_dumb       create a "dumb" built distribution
  bdist_rpm        create an RPM distribution
  bdist_wininst    create an executable installer for MS Windows
  upload           upload binary package to PyPI
  check            perform some checks on the package
```